# Pure css drop down menu over link with opacity

Tags: css, opacity

i am having a pure css drop down menu that works fine.

My problem is that behind the menu that opens i have links that use a .disable class with opacity 40% because they are not active.

When mouse over the menu (with link behind with opacity) the drop menu disappear and kind of focus on link with opacity.

If i remove the class that has opacity works fine.

Any ideas why and resolve it

Thanks

Comment: pure css menus usually don't work in IE6, 7, does it work for you?

Comment: in IE7 works fine.I design above IE7 so IE6 have not tested

Comment: what CSS properties are you using? try {display: block;} or {display: table;} will need to see the CSS to give you a better answer.

Comment: Help us help you http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Hi, could you please give us a link to an example page with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post some code?

I assume that your dropdown is a UL, within the parent UL LI. I would try to add position:relative, so the CSS would look like this:

```
ul li ul {
position: relative;
}
```

Does it work?